# How can the decimal mark for the current system locale be determined in R?

Tags: r, readr

I want to use `readr::parse_number()` for a character vector that was guessed as type "number" by `readr::guess_parser()`

I can construct a locale to make this work using `readr::parse_number( readr::locale(decimal_mark = <a mark to be determined at run time>) )`

So the issue is the system locale is unknown until runtime and could be anywhere in the world. Is there a way to determine the decimal mark from the system locale?

Comment: I think Sys.localeconv() could end up helping although it wont be pretty.

Comment: I might just use a line like `dec <- gsub("\\d", "", 0.1)` to pull the decimal mark from the output since the decimal mark of the current locale will print in the output

Comment: I've done some testing with the help of a colleague in Spain. I don't think this will work. It seems like the decimal mark for the locale is always "." in R. This makes sense because If you change it, it gives a warning about R not working as expected. The currency decimal`mon_decimal_point` seems to be set correctly. Maybe I can use this.